# Out of memory TriScatteredInterp in Matlab

Tags: matlab, out-of-memory, interpolation

I have encountered an out of memory problem when using `TriScatteredInterp`. I have a huge amount of data to be interpolated, and when I ask for an interpolation of a single point MATLAB returns an error.

```
x = rand(600000,1)*4-2;
y = rand(600000,1)*4-2;
z = rand(600000,1)*4-2;
T=rand(600000,1)*20-2;
>> F=TriScatteredInterp(x, y, z, T)

 F = 

 TriScatteredInterp

  Properties:
     X: [600000x3 double]
     V: [600000x1 double]
Method: 'linear'


F(.5773,1.6473,1.3403)
Error using TriScatteredInterp/subsref
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your
options.
```

I would like to know if someone has experienced a similar issue or if there is any possibility to enhance the code by spliting the data or something.

Comment: try to increase the swap file size

Comment: Have you tried using `scatteredInterpolant` instead? I read [scatteredInterpolant](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/scatteredinterpolant-class.html) is going to replace `TriScatteredInterp`, maybe the implementation is more memory efficient?

Comment: Unfurtonately my matlab version does not include that function, i have not tried if it resolves this problem.

Comment: You can definitely work this out by splitting the data like you suggested. Sort the data points into blocks in x-y-z, create a TriScatteredInterp object for each block, and only interpolate inside the relevant block for every new position.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to split the data as you suggested:

```
%% Original data
x = rand(600000,1)*4-2;
y = rand(600000,1)*4-2;
z = rand(600000,1)*4-2;
T=rand(600000,1)*20-2;

%% No data splitting
F=TriScatteredInterp(x, y, z, T);

tic
F(.5773,1.6473,1.3403)
toc

%% Split into 8 blocks
blockBorders = -2:2:2;
F = cell(8,1);
ii = 1;
for ix = 1:2
    for iy = 1:2
        for iz = 1:2
            inBlock = (x >= blockBorders(ix)) & (x < blockBorders(ix+1)) &...
                (y >= blockBorders(iy)) & (y < blockBorders(iy+1)) &...
                (z >= blockBorders(iz)) & (z < blockBorders(iz+1));
            F{ii} = TriScatteredInterp(x(inBlock), y(inBlock), z(inBlock), T(inBlock));
            ii = ii + 1;
        end
    end
end

tic
p = [.5773,1.6473,1.3403];
ix = find((p(1) >= blockBorders(1:end-1)) & (p(1) < blockBorders(2:end)));
iy = find((p(2) >= blockBorders(1:end-1)) & (p(2) < blockBorders(2:end)));
iz = find((p(3) >= blockBorders(1:end-1)) & (p(3) < blockBorders(2:end)));
ii = ix*4 + iy*2 + iz - 6;
F{ii}(p(1), p(2), p(3));
toc
```

My machine does not reproduce your memory issue, but shows a runtime difference: 0.246633 seconds for the first method and 0.141250 seconds for the second method. This is indicative of the smaller amount of data being processed, and could possibly solve your problem.

You can always split your data even more if it increases in size, but be wary that you are in effect interpolating over a smaller part of xyz space and this could possibly be problematic, depending on the nature of your data. In fact, the implementation given here is problematic too because there is no overlap between interpolation blocks, so points near block borders are probably interpolated poorly. However this is a start and a possible way to avoid memory and runtime issues.